# naming question - non programmatic question

Tags: naming-conventions

I have two tables in my db: Customers and Subcontractors.

Now it appears that some customers can be also subcontractors.

What I decided to do is to create a base table (super type) that holds the common data and then complete the relevant info for each type (customer, subcontractor) in other table. It will be something like this:

```
 NEW_TABLE<------Customers
          <------Subcontractors
```

The problem is that I don't really know what to call this table. Is the name "Partner" the best option?

Comment: What's the domain you're dealing with? Partner sounds ok, but there may be a better term for the domain

Comment: Yes, transportation is the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with the other responders.  More information about the domain is needed before getting really useful answers.

But I'd suggest `ThirdParty` or `ExternalParty`, since I'm assuming `Customers` and `Subcontractors` are external to your business.  Internal parties could be `User`, `InternalParty`, etc.

I think you've tagged this question properly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can answer your question without knowing the domain.
It can be partner, contact, company.

Answer (score 1):

'Party' may be a good name. You can find [this](http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/advanceddm.htm) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/716549/625332) interesting. Or just google "Database Party Model".

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, there are two main options:

1. Have a single table called `third_party` that has a `party_type` column of either `'customer'` or '`subcontractor`' (and others and time goes by, like '`supplier`' etc).
   The details are largely contact details, which are common to all third parties
2. Have two tables like you have now, but store the common data in a separate table, for example `contact_details`, and have a foreign key from both tables to that details record. When a customer is also a contractor, both records would point to the same details record.

I prefer option 2, because it allows different relationships to exist for each type.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it `SubcontractorBase`, but as Peri points out it is hard to say without knowing the domain

Answer (score 0):

What about having a single table, with all of the options (however named) as BOOLs so that you could easily indicate when a party belongs in more than one group (you'd also be able to add categories as needed in the future)

Comment: The problem will be that there will br many unused columns for each row.