# database design, connecting common data of different entities

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, class-table-inheritance, shared-primary-key

We have entities like Customer, Broker, Company. These have different attributes and must be on different tables. But they can have common things, in our case Contact Info 
(entity->contact is one to many relationship).
Whats the best way to do that. If there isnt a perfect design, what is best if the most important thing is to write the least code possible.

case 1: all entities have a 'common' auto-inc entityId ( they share the primary key , so you cant have a Customer with id=1 and a Company with id=1)
[image]

case 2: 'contact' stores information about what entity it refers to. (Customers, Companies, Brokers dont share primary key)

[image]

case 3: 3 contact tables, one for each of our entities.

There are more ways to connect those tables, and its a problem frequently occuring, i dont particularly like any solution, so help me decide.

Comment: Check out **super-type/subtype** http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a196713%20subtype
and **Party**  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716549/what-are-the-principles-behind-and-benefits-of-the-party-model

Comment: Also check put class-table-inheritance.  There is some overlap with party.  They are both worth looking at