# How to structure data in a relational schema where related data is not a case of a simple join

Tags: database-design

I have database design quandry...

My system has a series of "missions" and each mission can be assigned either to a single hard-bitten individual or a well-oiled team of crack experts.

Thinking about the usage of the system...

- Most commonly a person would connect to the system to find out what mission(s) they are assigned to.
- The next most common thing would be that someone would be assigning teams or individuals to missions
- And thirdly, of course, there is always the possibility that this coordinator would be wanting to check who is assigned where and to juggle around the personnel as is their wont

My first thought is that a structure like this would be just the ticket:

[image: Option 1]

The thing is, in that case, my most common query would have to look something like this:

```
declare @name nvarchar(1000)
set @name = ...

declare @myId int

-- find out my user id
set @myId = (select top 1 IndividualId from Individuals where Name = @name)

-- Now find all the missions where I am am member of a team that's been assigned
select a.Name
from Missions a
inner join IndividualsInTeams b on a.TeamId = b.TeamId
where a.TeamAssigned = 1 and b.IndividualId = @myId

-- And UNION that with all the missions where I have been solely assigned

union

select  Name
from Missions
where TeamAssigned = 0 and IndividualId = @myId
```

I figure I can smooth this over by creating a view (called MissionsWithIndividuals ) like so:

```
select  a.Name As 'MissionName', c.Name As 'IndividualName'
from Missions a
inner join IndividualsInTeams b on a.TeamId = b.TeamId
inner join Individuals c on b.IndividualId = c.IndividualId
where a.TeamAssigned = 1 

union

select a.Name As 'MissionName', b.Name As 'IndividualName'
from Missions a
inner join Individuals b on b.IndividualId = a.IndividualId
where TeamAssigned = 0
```

And then my most common query would be:

```
select MissionName from MissionsWithIndividuals where IndividualName = @name
```

But that feels kind of dodgy.

I mean, aren't I having to make the database go through a whole bunch of hoops to deal with my most common query.  Wouldn't it be better if my data were structured in a way that makes my most common query more natural?

Also, I open the possibility that a mission is assigned to an individual AND a team and that is not really allowed (if it is more than a single person it must be within an allocated team).

I could go instead with this:

[image: option 2]

But that, whilst making my most common query easy, feels a bit horrible due to the multi-purpose nature of the TeamOrIndividualName and the fact that I cannot put a constraint on it.

So, what would be the best way to structure my data in this case?

Is there another possibility that I have not considered?

Comment: I would be tempted to put every individual on a single person team, so that I had the following relationships: Individual -> Team -- Mission.

Comment: What about a MissionsAssigned table that simply holds the MissionID and either a TeamID or an IndividualID

Comment: "*either to a single hard-bitten individual or a well-oiled team of crack experts*"  Hmm, those are good choices to have.  I am usually limited to either a single well-oiled individual or a hard-bitten team of crakpots.  :-(

Comment: use the Party Model. An Individual is a Party and so is a Team. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716549/what-are-the-principles-behind-and-benefits-of-the-party-model

Comment: Can multiple teams be assigned to the same mission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was suggested by Gilbert Le Blanc I think the solution here is to link missions to teams, even if the team has a single person in it. This removes the possibility that someone assigns a person *AND* and team to a mission and removes the need to have a `UNION` query. This *will* however force you to do 3 joins (Missions -> Teams, Teams -> IndividualsInTeams, IndividualsInTeams -> Individuals). If that is too costly then I suggest you create a static view on your data everyday if you can tolerate data that is not live. Depending on your database size the view may or may not be costly to generate. Depending on the time cost you may want to update it twice a day to have more accurate data. That would save you time for your most important queries (what missions are assigned to user X ?).