# Schema Design for User Settings

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, database-design, settings

I am developing a website with user authentication. I need to implement settings for each users. I found a solution. But I need more better solution.

My solution is given below.

> I have 2 tables, UserTable and SettingsTable. I created a new table
>   UserSettings for relating the UserTable and SettingsTable as shown below

[image: user settings schema]

But there is several type of users Like **super_admin**, **managers**, **supervisors** and **normal_users**. They are in a top down manner.

There are privileges.

- Super_admin can give privileges to others
- Managers can give privileges to supervisors and noraml_users
- supervisors can give privileges to normal_users.

Please help me to find a better solution.

Comment: Are those "settigns" used ONLY for users ? if so, I do not really see the need for 3 separate tables ...

Comment: What is it you don't like about this solution (what would be "better")?

Comment: There is a super_user who can give permissions to other users to edit their settings or can set default value for each settings. In this situation how to modify the above schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution for this is to develop a role based system. **User**,**Role**,**RolePermissions**, **RoleSettings** and if Individual user settings is required we can go for Settings and User Settings

Other wise you should follow some defined data model implementations like following

1. Party Model
2. Role based Access COntrol

Reference :

> http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/07/30/modeling-people-and-organizations-class-party.aspx
>
> http://siebeloracle.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/party-data-model-siebel-eim-party_type_cd-s_party/
>
> [What are the principles behind, and benefits of, the "party model"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716549/what-are-the-principles-behind-and-benefits-of-the-party-model)
>
> http://siebeloracle.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/party-data-model-siebel-eim-party_type_cd-s_party/
>
> http://www.dataqualityfirst.com/party_data_definition.htm

roles

> http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/post/2009/01/02/from+len+silverstons+party+role+model+to+physical+tables+in+erstudio.aspx
>
> http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/role-based-access-control.html

Party Relationships

> http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5014/