# Database Relationship Model for a blood bank with many user types

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Here we have a fake company, a Blood Bank. The core idea is that only donors can donate blood but cannot log into the system. However, a "registered user" (rows in the `user` table) that represents a company can log into the system and see the amount of blood that their company has donated. Donors must be connected to companies. In a fringe case, a "registered user" can also donate blood.

- User = A "registered user". Can log in.
- Donor = Cannot log in.
- Admin = A site administrators. Can log in.
- Blood bank employee = Self explanatory. Can log in.

There might be other types of users in the future, like differentiating types of "registered users". Maybe, just maybe.

## SOLUTION 1

- Separate donor table.

[image]

PROS:

- Queries to find donors will be faster, especially if the table grows large

CONS:

- What to do if a donor suddenly wants to log in? Create a duplicate entry in the `user` table?
- What if a "registered user" wants to donate? Create a duplicate entry in the `donor` table?

## SOLUTION 2

Use ACL `role`/`user_role` tables to define donors (and other user types)

[image]

PROS:

- Easy to handle a donor that wants to later login as a "registered user"
- Easy to handle a "registered user" that later wants to become a donor
- Also easier to promote any user to an admin

CONS:

- There are fields that donors do not need, like 'password', 'throttled', so
  **There will be extra NULLs**

## SOLUTION 3

Identical to Solution 2, except creating an additional table `user_type`. This would be done to avoid re-using the ACL system for controlling log in & user account type details.

## SOLUTION 4

Aggregate user.
[image]

This is based on user1759572's suggestion to use an aggregate user. I may not have modeled it exactly right.


Which option would you go with? Is there a 4th.. 5th option.. something better?

***Any reply is very much appreciated***. This will help me nail down a final bit of design that I've been bouncing around on for a few days now. Arg. Thanks you SO!

Comment: Do you search for the best way or a pragmatic one?

Comment: My hope is that they are the same. Probably the best way, or at least what doesn't violate any obvious design best practices that I might have overlooked

Comment: Could you explain your domain logic here. From the 1 as I see only companies manage the donors and their blood? yes? It it a requirement now?

Comment: One more way would be aggregate USERS table to other entities and have something like `Company [1-*] Donor, 
Company [1-1] User, 
Donor   [1-1] User, 
User    [1-*] ACL rules `

Comment: In the roles above, Admins, Users, "Blood bank employee" would be able to manage donors and their blood. However, a User would only be able to manage his/her own companies donors, where Admins and "Blood bank employee" could manage any donor. Yes, this would be a requirement. A "soft" requirement

Comment: So what does that mean. Company has people, some of the people are donors, some are users and some are both. So in other words you have 2 ways: 1.Aggregate Person to a User and a Donor.(you have some users, if you know some info on them create person row. you have some donors - add it to donors table. If you know more info on that donor create row person. if user wants to donate, just connect donor to a person, if a donor wants to be user, just connect person to a user.) so in other way, user now is like credentials - don't have credentials cant login :)

Comment: Way 2. If you think a user is "something" that uses a system and a donor is "something" that gives blood then you have another way, you just create that something and add a flags to it. So "Something" now has a Donor flag. If it needs to login "Something" set a User flag(with credentials) and its ready to go. so these 2 are similar, but the logic changes...

Comment: user1759572, im still trying to wrap my head around aggregate person method you described, particularly why the Company-User connection is 1-1. I will add that option the original post soon. Way 2 sounds a lot like Solution2 in the original post, where the `user` table is the "something" and the `role` table defines the flags that allows donor or login status. The main problem I have with that is that many of the fields in a "something/user" table, like throttled, password, would be null for a donor type of user. I hope I understood your comment correctly. Thank you for the quick responses

Comment: i am sorry I did a mistake in that comment.... It should be `Company [1-*] Donor, Company [1-*] Person, Person [1-1] User, Donor [1-1] User, User [1-*] ACL rules`(this is kind of 3 of my suggested ways) And yes 2 way is kind of yours :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36684/discussion-between-user1759572-and-stabby-lorenzo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [Party Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716549/what-are-the-principles-behind-and-benefits-of-the-party-model) and Party Role model. An individual or organization (such as a company) inherit from an abstract Legal Party. A party can play many roles, such a Donor, Staff.
2. Instead of rolling your own user and group logins, I would use a database that supports real users and groups, and updatable views, WITH CHECK OPTION.