# Store login information in one table in school database with conditional relation

Tags: database, relational-database, relation

I want to design a database for my school's website. There is some roles that you can find in any school: Students, Teachers, Parents, Employees.

Each role has some information that is not usable for other roles; For example only students must have a "Student Number" and this is not usable for other roles. In other hand, each role has some functionality that others don't have; For example for designing a table for school's schedule, there must be a field to specify every period's teacher and must relate to teachers only.

Totally it seems that these roles must be kept in separate tables; One for students, another for teachers etc.

Now I want to design a login system for my website. I prefer that to be centralized and everybody can login in a single page. Additionally, I want to implement an ACL system for access management. It seems that I must have a table for login information.

Now here is the problem. I want to relate my login table to the role tables(students, teacher, etc.). I must have a field for storing role, and another for the target table's id. For example when role is teacher, the id field refers to if of teachers' table.

What do you think about my solution? Is it standard to have something that I call it "Conditional Relation"? Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Table Inheritance](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html).

Read up on [The Party Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716549/what-are-the-principles-behind-and-benefits-of-the-party-model).