# Design a database to track the owner

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

In my business logic, I have a user, a company (users can be part of the company, as employees,  i would call them "agents") and products.

A product can be owned by a user or by a company, the company can assign it to a user (agent) later, but it would still be owned by the company (in case the company fires the agent).

My thought is to have the user table, the company table and the product table and a table to track who is the owner of the product:

```
--------------
|   users    | 
--------------
|   user_id  |
|  name      |
--------------
--------------
|   products |
--------------
| product_id |
|  title     |
--------------
--------------
|   company  |
--------------
| company_id |
|  name      |
--------------

--------------
|   agents   |
--------------
| agent_id   |
|  user_id   |
| company_id |
--------------

----------------
|product_owner |
----------------
|     id       |
|  product_id  |
|  user_id     |
|  company_id  |
|agent_assigned|
----------------
```

If the product is owned by a user then only product_id and user_id will be filled. If it's owned by a company, then product_id, company_id and agent_assigned would be filled.

Later, I would want to pull a product, and know who's the owner: the user info, or the agent and company info.

Is this the best way to do it? It doesn't seem that good to me.

Comment: We have a contacts database. Every contact HAS to belong to (at least) one organisation, but some of those organisations are a little abstract - e.g. 'project x client group'. So in your scenario, every product would be owned by an organisation, even though some of those organisations are in a sense fictitious. This question doesn't conform strictly to SO's requirements, but I'm 1-upping it anyway, 'cause I like it.

Comment: Its not necessary to store company_id in product_owner - this information is already held in the agents table. another possibility is to store owner_id always in the same field and add another field which defines the owner type

Comment: Why not: Owner_type, Owner_ID, slave_type, slave_ID. And just ram every possible relation in there. This way everything can be handled the same way and you allow items to be assigned to multiple owners too. OT = 'company', OI = company_id_2, ST = 'product', SI = product_id_25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard [Party Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716549/what-are-the-principles-behind-and-benefits-of-the-party-model). Read up on [Table](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) Inheritance to implement it.

An asset is owned by a legal party. It could be an individual, group of individuals (say the Jones family), a government, a company. You need to abstract these concrete types to one abstract type so that you can point a single foreign key at them.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your requirements I don't think you are too far off. I would separate the products that belong to company and user however and make it into something like this:

[image]

Then when you need to pull a product and find the owner you just need a join query. Something like this:

```
select * from product p 
left join companyproduct cp on p.id = cp.product 
join productowner po on cp.productid = po.productid 
join agent a on po.userid = a.userid 
where p.id = ?  AND a.userid = ?
```

I'm not saying that syntax is correct or will work for you, it is just an example of what you would need to do.

Comment: The thing with this solution is that the ProdcutOwner would only have a userid. What if the Company "fires" the Agent. Then the product would be without an owner. I want to keep the company as the owner of the product, even if I fire the agent

Comment: The way you are describing it, you would have the default value of `NULL` in `userid` on the `ProductOwner` page? This is a bad design which is why I chose to separate them into `ProductOwner` and `CompanyOwner`. If an agent is fired then the record from `ProductOwner` could just be deleted whereas you will retain the record of which company owns the product in `CompanyProduct`. At least, that's how I view the design.

Comment: Ok. I might be a little bit confused. Then, if I want to see if the product is owned by a user, an agent or just by a company, I would have to look in the CompanyProducts first and then in ProductOwner every time? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your description, is a user always an agent? And is a product always owned by a company? If so then you would definitely need join queries on such tables to find the information you want. If a product can only be owned by one entity at a time then that is a different situation.

Comment: No. An agent is always a user, but a user doesnt need to be an agent. A Product can be owned by a company or by a user. The company can set up an agent (who is a user) as owner, but only temporarily. Instead of owner, maybe a better word the agent is "responsible" for the product. And it's possible for a product to have more than one agent responsible of it